# Hide PHP file extension on URL (Even when someone manually puts .php at the end)

Tags: php, .htaccess

**My .htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html


</IfModule>
```

Hello currently my system works fine and I can have links without .php at the end, but I want to go one step further, and make it so if someone was to enter .php at the end manually for if the link is www.example.com/account

Changing it to www.example.com/account.php would produce a 404 error?

Is this possible?

Thank you very much, I am very grateful for any responses I get!

Comment: You could use a router instead. Then you can have all the files outside of the document root and make up what URL's you want and none of the files would be directly accessible.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson How would I do this?

Comment: You can go to [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/search/?q=router&hPP=20&idx=packagist&p=0&search_query%5Bquery%5D=router&is_v=1) and search for some router library that you like. Then just read on how to implement it and try.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I would prefer to do it in .htaccess to keep it simple anubhava has the right idea of what I am wanting! Thank you anyway :)

Comment: A router *is* the simple way, quite frankly. Any modern framework like Laravel will function in this way.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you so much for your help, but anubhava has done exactly what I needed, I am sure your way would have worked too! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine on` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php or /dir/file.html to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.(?:php|html?)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

# your existing rules go below this
```

This will return 404 for `www.example.com/account.php` or `www.example.com/account.html`

Comment: Hello, this is almost what I want, thank you very much friend, but someone could still know that I was using PHP as if they put .aspx it would not do anything at all.

Is it possible to make any extension at the end redirect to /account?

Comment: Or if now, how would I make it just produce a 404 error?

Comment: All of the other extensions produce a 404 error, how can I make the .html and .php extensions do the same? Thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: You are a genius, thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: I have selected your answer as the correct one, thanks.